# Python requests retrieve html of website after a certain time

Tags: python, python-requests

In certain websites, after connecting to the website there is a loading logo, then a post request is made, and then the actual website is shown. What I want is for the program to send the request, allow for the post request to go through and the html to load, then retrieve the html. The way that I am currently getting the request is through this code:

```
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=self.headers_normal, timeout=(self.requestTimeout, self.waitTime))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
```

The wait time is the amount of time after the request goes through to get the html of the website. I saw one person say that with the timeout function you can set it to a timeout where the first argument is the timeout for a connection to be established, and the second argument is the time after the connection is established to grab the website html. However, that is incorrect. The second argument is actually a timeout for being able to retrieve the html. Is there a way to do what I want where it waits a certain amount of time before grabbing the html?

Comment: More likely that javascript is loading the content in which case you need something other than requests, e.g., Selenium, to get at the generated HTML.

Comment: `requests` isn’t a browser - it will send a get and receive the response, only making multiple requests if the server redirects and if redirects are enabled. if you want browser-like behaviour you should maybe use Selenium?

Comment: What you need to do is replicate the request that actually loads the website.

Comment: To explain: what a browser does is do the GET for the URL you want to open, then it goes through what it receives (html which references images+css+javascript) and does GET for these e.g. images, css, javascript files, then runs the JS which can do more GETs or whatever it wants. Your `requests` GET just does that first part. You could try to write code to do the following steps, i.e. try to simulate a browser,, but a more sensible and practical and likely successful approach would be to use Selenium to do everything because it is basically a browser with a Python API.